# Configuring promtail/loki to read from cold storage (Azure storage account)

Tags: azure, logging, grafana-loki, azure-diagnostics, promtail

All the audit logs from a running cluster get stored to "insights-logs-*" containers in an Azure storage account. This was already configured in the "diagnostic settings" section in the Azure Kubernetes Service.

I would like to introduce Loki for cost-effective logging and have managed to configure the storage in the Helm loki-distributed setup so that the logs get stored to a storage account back-end, after giving the node pool the "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role.

How can I configure Promtail in loki-distributed so that it can process the old audit logs stored by Azure diagnostic settings?

I tried checking if someone else had a similar question regarding feeding Promtail log files from Azure storage accounts, but so far only found answers related to archiving the logs in Azure.

Comment: Here is a work-around to use Azure Event Hubs as an alternative destination for the diagnostic logs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78075726/ingesting-logs-from-azure-blob-storage-to-loki/78152668#78152668